# LinqPad Displays Invalid object name 'dbo.sysforeignkeys'

Tags: azure, linqpad

Using LinqPad to connect to Azure SQL Database. T-SQL query (`Select * from dimGrade`) returns all 20 records, but C# expression (`from g in dimGrade select g or dimGrade.Take(20)`) throws an error

> Invalid object name 'dbo.sysforeignkeys'

How do I configure Linq to SQL for an Azure SQL Database?

LinqPad 4.51.03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the very same problem.
I've realized, that I didn't make connection properly.

Instead of "SQL Azure" I left SQL Server.
Linqpad will connect, but mentioned error will popout.

[image]